# Docker service startup failed with status 203

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, rhel7, docker-engine

I have a RHEL 7 server with Docker EE and I have installed Docker CE after removing Docker EE. But after installing Docker CE, when I try to start Docker service with command `systemctl enable --now docker`, it is failing with below error.

```
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When I see the status of Docker service (`systemctl status docker.service`), I see below error.

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status docker.service
  docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           httpd.conf, comp_config.conf
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Sun 2024-03-24 11:00:00 CDT; 3s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 24653 ExecStopPost=/var/lib/docker/scripts/dockerd-shutdown.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
  Process: 24651 ExecStartPre=/var/lib/docker/scripts/mount-overlay2fs.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
systemd[1]: docker.service holdout time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for docker.service
systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine. 
systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for docker.service
systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

**How Docker EE removed?**

I removed Docker EE by doing following steps.

- Stopped Docker services
- yum remove docker-ee and other docker packages.

**Steps followed to install Docker** -
Followed steps from https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-docker-in-rhel-8 to install Docker CE.

How can I fix this? Where I should start looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give a try to the following procedure, I tested it in Oracle Linux 7.9 and it worked.

1. Update system packages

```bash
sudo yum update
```

2. Install required dependencies

```bash
sudo yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2
```

3. Set up Docker CE repository

```bash
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
```

4. Install Docker CE

```bash
sudo yum install docker-ce
```

5. Start **THEN** enable Docker service

```bash
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

6. Verify Docker installation

```bash
sudo docker --version
```

Comment: I followed the same steps. Docker was installed but when starting the Docker service, I'm seeing the error.

Comment: @noonenine is SELinux enabled in your server (`sestatus`) ? If so can you try to start the service once SELinux in permisive mode (`setenforce 0`)?